# windows-server-2003 missing logical drives after HBA SAS card was replaced

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell-perc, microsoft-cluster-server

Both servers run windows-server-2003 x64 in a Active/Standby Microsoft Cluster with shared Disk Resources.
Server1
Server2

Server1 suffered hardware issues needing HBA SAS card replaced. Disk Management no longer detects the shared logical drives on it. These drives are part of Disk Resources in the cluster.

Based on my research, Microsoft Cluster uses Disk Signature to identify & attach to the Disk Resources.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/280425/recovering-from-an-event-id-1034-on-a-server-cluster

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/886800/a-disk-signature-changes-unexpectedly-on-a-windows-server-2003-clustered-physical-disk-resource

An issue I see are missing REG_SZ DiskName entries in the registry.

Example:

```
reg query     HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Clusdisk\Parameters\Signatures\D441B580
Listing of [System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Clusdisk\Parameters\Signatures\D484B580]
REG_SZ DiskName \Device\Harddisk1
```

Do I simply need to add the missing registry keys on Server1 to make it appear in Disk Management?

EDIT: 
Both servers run on Dell PowerEdge 6850.

Looking at Dell Modular Disk Storage Manager on each server the following looks correct.
Configured Hosts
Host Name : HBA Hosts Ports mapping

Host-to-virtual disk mappings

Windows Device Manager:
SCSI and RAID controllers

DELL PERC 5/i Adapter RAID Controller
Dell SAS 5/E Adapter Controller (I believe this is what connects to the shared storage)

LSI Logic PCI-x Ultra320 SCSI Host Adapter

LSI Logic PCI-x Ultra320 SCSI Host Adapter

MagicISO SCSI Host Controller

Multi-Path Support

A new observation is Windows Disk Mangement has Disk 0 assigned to Virtual CD ROM on Server1.
On Server2, Disk 0 is the C:\ OS drive.

The logical drives needs to be presented as Disks 1,2,3,5. 
Since Disk 1 is already in use by Windows could this prevent entire Logical drives not to be presented to Windows?

Comment: "shared Disk Resources" - what type of disk resource, a SAS-connected storage array?

Comment: What *physically* is the shared storage? An external array?

Comment: External drive array managed by Dell Modular Disk Storage Manager. I remotely manage the device so do not have visual access to the cabinet physically.

Comment: Wow, Ultra320 SCSI cards? This thing has been in action for a good while...

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

Assuming your "shared disk resource" is on an external storage array of some kind, you will most likely need to update the host mapping for the array's access control list. A storage array will essentially "see" a new HBA's WWN as a totally different server/system until you modify configuration to tell it this new WWN should replace the old one.

If you have details on what specific hardware/solution is being used for the shared storage resource, you're likely to receive much better information regarding the specific process involved.

Edit: 
That's going to be a PowerVault MD3000 based on the SAS5/E and MDSM used for management.

I strongly suspect this is just a host mapping issue. The MD3000 is configured to present the shared disks to specific HBA hardware addresses (WWNs). You need to change the host mapping configuration so that the replacement HBA's WWN is used for host access instead of the old. If you have not done this yet, your host will not have access to the shared volumes.

Check out the [MDSM User's Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powervault/powervault-md3000_user%27s%20guide20_en-us.pdf) - configuring host access begins on page 43, but the details are too extensive to include in this post. If you're unable to find an option to modify the existing host WWN definition and are afraid of mistakenly removing the wrong one, you could simply add a 3rd "host" entry with the new WWN mapped - there's no harm in leaving the old HBA/host entry in there since it's dead and gone.

If you get stuck and can't get things figured out, Dell support can still assist with this process (though there's a service fee since if system is out of warranty). It's only with the old SCSI-attached enclosures that you'll find difficulty tracking down anyone who still has any expertise who hasn't retired or left.

Comment: Looking at Dell Modular Disk Storage Manager on each server the LUN mappings looks correct. I added details to original post thanks!